# Multi Objective Optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymoo

I am a beginner when it comes to python and especially to Optimization.  I have looked through the pymoo docs and they seem quite confusing. How would I find the most efficient results from points with three values each. Pymoo has these things called "problems" and I am confused on how I would make one.  Can anyone explain simply (any help would be appreciated)
Thanks

Comment: Please explain your problem in a more detailed way. What optimization problem are you going to solve in pymoo?

Comment: @alisher592 I have a set of data points with three values each and would like to know the most optimal ones (maximizing)

Comment: have you formulated an objective function and constraints?